# Is it possible to say so very and very so?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, adverbs, word-order, adverb-position

I know that it is correct to use:

> Thank you **so very** much.

As much as I know an adverb can be theoretically used to modify another adverb, so my question is:

> Is it possible to say **very so much**?

Or even, if something is "so very red", can it be "very so red"?

Comment: "Pal, I could kick your butt from here to Wednesday." "Oh, *is that so*?" "*Very so*". So yes, in theory, it's possible. In practice, Google Ngrams suggests essentially **no one** says or has ever said "very so" (and fewer and fewer people are saying "so very" as time goes on): https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=so+very%2C+very+so&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cso%20very%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvery%20so%3B%2Cc0

Comment: "I'm so **very so**-rry".  ;)

Comment: @DanBron I've heard of "very much so" but not "very so". I think this is just language evolution at work, new phrases and whatnot get invented and people start shifting their usage, e.g. *Oll Korrect*

Comment: (that was probably "orl korrect" (r) .. but, who knows?)

Comment: Hey Raes - just saw your comment.  "very much so" is completely commonplace, I hear it every week.  maybe it's a regional thing.  (it reminds me of how people in just certain parts of london say "thank you so much" (in a snarky/sarcastic way), it's a shibboleth...)

Answer (score 2):

> Stuart: Ooh, Sheldon, I’m afraid you couldn’t be more wrong.
>
> Sheldon: "More wrong"? Wrong is an absolute state and not subject to gradation.

Like *wrong*, *so* is absolute.  "So much" means literally "exactly this much", and you cannot be "very exactly" anything.

> Stuart: Of course it is. It’s a little wrong to say a tomato is a vegetable, it’s very wrong to say it’s a suspension bridge.

Comment: Well, everyone utterly ignores [joke] the fact that "wrong" is an absolute. indeed, I would go so far as to say, in English, the idea of absolutes being non-modifiable is, plain, wrong. since 99% of people add modifiers 99% of the time.  You know - once spelling changes, say, it has changed, and it's now "correct"

Answer (score -2):

Note that the phrase:

"very much so"

is completely commonplace.

"Are you happy?" "Very much so."  "Do they make Champagne in Burgundy?" "Very much so."

Comment: They make Champagne there? Better tell the authorities!

Comment: Heh .. good one.  I couldn't resist putting in an impromptu essay on that

Comment: Unfortunately it had nothing to do with the answer (although it's still available in the edit history).